# Is there a way in using firestore that will print a message using flutter if an array contains a string

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way in using firestore that will print a message using flutter if an array contains a string.

I want to check if the array inside a specific document has the user email inside it. If the array contains the user email, it will show a message.

here's my current code but it is not working.

```
(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where(
                                'requests',
                                arrayContains: user.email)  == true)
                        ? Text("true")
                        : Text("false");
```

Comment: can you clarify what do you want to achive exactly, do you want to check over a array field in a specific document, or do you want to search over a whole collection to get what documents have a list field that contains that value ?

Comment: I want to check if the array inside a document has the user email inside it. If the array contains the user email, it will show a message.

Answer (score 1):

get the list of user emails from firestore and store in a local list [listName]. Then call listName.contains(userEmail) and store the result in a bool variable.
Like this,

```
  bool isEmailexist =  usersList.contains(userEmail);
```

Finally you can display your message by checking bool value.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have merely declares a query. It doesn't yet execute that query, so there's no way yet it can check whether there are any results.

To execute the query, you will need to either call `get()` (as shown in the documentation on [getting data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)) or `snapshots()` (as shown in the documentation on [listening for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)).

Both operations are asynchronous, so you will have to handle that in your widgets. For `get()`, which returns a `Future`, you can use a `FutureBuilder`, while for `snapshots`, which returns a `Stream`, you can use a `StreamBuilder`.